# Python multiprocessing Pool hangs on ubuntu server

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I'm running Django on an Ubuntu server with nginx and gunicorn. I'm trying to do some multiprocessing which is working on my local machine but hangs until the gunicorn worker times out on my server.

```
cpu_count = int(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
pool = Pool(processes = cpu_count)
result = pool.map_async(apiSimulAvail, rate_ranges)
result.wait()

...do some more stuff once all processes return
```

It hangs at `pool = Pool(processes = cpu_count)`. I don't get any errors, the gunicorn worker just times out and reboots.

Any indication as to why this is happening and/or how I can solve it is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you start any threads before you started these processes?

Comment: What do you mean "that view"?  If a process hangs, it could be because it inherited bad synchronization state from a parent, or grand-parent or great-grandparent... process.  The best, possibly only, way to insure this can never happen is to never start processes after any threads have been started.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Using Python Version 2.7

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a variation on [Using python's Multiprocessing makes response hang on gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175090/using-pythons-multiprocessing-makes-response-hang-on-gunicorn) so possibly this is a dupe.

That said do you have to use multiprocessing (MP)? You might honestly be better served farming this out to something like Celery. MP might be getting killed with the gunicorn worker when it dies since it owns the MP process. Depending on the server config, that could happen pretty frequently. If you've got some very long running kind of job you can still farm that out to Celery, it's just a bit more configuration.

Comment: Django and Gunicorn are not suited for long-lived connection, so +1 on the Celery suggestion. If the task is long, it should not block the connection (and should be done elsewhere). If the task is short... then why bother with multiprocessing?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using some async Gunicorn worker? If so, try the default sync worker and see if you can reproduce the problem.

If the problem can only be reproduced when using async workers, you should make sure the `multiprocessing` module is patched correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your answer. What do you mean by patching multiprocessing module?

Comment: It looks like it's to do with gevent, that I was using as worker-class for gunicorn. Removing that fixes the hanging issue at least. Any idea how to get it work with gevent?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
pool = Pool(processes = cpu_count)
```

to

```
pool = Pool(cpu_count)
```

This assumes that you've imported Pool from multiprocessing otherwise you'll need to do

```
multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_count)
```

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion but this results in the same issue. Runs on my local machine but hangs on my server.

Comment: Do you have the same python version on both machines?

Comment: No, my local machine has 2.7.5 while the server has 2.7.6. As I look through the release notes for 2.7.6 it looks like all bug fixes and I don't see anything indicating that it created a new issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by giving each gunicorn worker a fixed amount of tasks to execute setting `maxtasksperchild` argument like this `Pool(..., maxtasksperchild=1)`. In this way each gunicorn worker is freed up automatically after completing the given tasks.

This is what Pool [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) tells:

> *Worker processes within a Pool typically live for the complete duration of the Pool’s work queue. A frequent pattern found in other systems (such as Apache, mod_wsgi, etc) to free resources held by workers is to allow a worker within a pool to complete only a set amount of work before being exiting, being cleaned up and a new process spawned to replace the old one. The maxtasksperchild argument to the Pool exposes this ability to the end user.*