# Model hangs when using gunicorn with joblib parallel

Tags: flask, gunicorn, joblib

I am facing a very tricky problem. Needed some help on the same.
I am using nginx, gunicorn and flask to expose an API for one of the model. Gunicorn is running with a single worker and flask api invokes the model.
Model uses joblib to run few things in parallel. For the model, I see that when joblib parallel is invoked, the processing starts to hang.

Not sure what is causing this. Please suggest if there is specific settings that I am missing in gunicorn.

Important thing is that when I run my flask api without gunicorn, joblib's parallel is invoked successfully and completes execution. Also, since I use docker, when I limit the container to use single core, then processing completes execution.

Code where it hangs:

```
results = parallel(delayed(func)(b) for b in batches)
```

In Output, I see below lines which hangs:

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Using backend MultiprocessingBackend with 4 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done   7 out of  10 | elapsed:    1.9s remaining:    0.8s
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done  10 out of  10 | elapsed:    2.1s finished
```

I see there are few links in stackoverflow mentioning similar problem, but did not get specific solution to problem, for example : [Using python's Multiprocessing makes response hang on gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175090/using-pythons-multiprocessing-makes-response-hang-on-gunicorn)